# Adding namescpace prefix to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a number of POCO classes that are generating the required XML structure for serializtion to be passed as return in a SOAP WS. In selected elements I need to add namespace prefix/ alais to the elements. Is this possible? If yes how please?

POCO Classes

```
public partial class ValueTable
{

    private List<ValueTableColumn> headerField;

    private row[] rowField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("column", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<ValueTableColumn> header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }


    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlElement]
    public row[] row
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rowField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rowField = value;
        }
    }

}
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class row
{

    private rowField[] fieldField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("field")]
    public rowField[] field
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fieldField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fieldField = value;
        }
    }
}
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class rowField
{

    private string textField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.textField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample XML with required namespace prefixes/alias

```
    <v21:row>
            <v21:field>
                <v21:text>ID-1005896</v21:text>
            </v21:field>
            <v21:field>
                <v21:text>Smith</v21:text>
            </v21:field>
<v21:field>
                <v21:text>64AF6547DDSEE</v21:text>
            </v21:field>
        </v21:row>
```

Currently it is being returned with out the prefixes/alias.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: not sure what specific api you're dealing with; one [XmlElement] attribute lets you add a Namespace argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=net-6.0  like `[XmlElement(
   ElementName = "Members",
   Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]`

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.XPath;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValueTable));
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XPathNavigator xPathNavigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
var nameSpaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
nameSpaces.Add("yourPrefix", "http://your.namespace.com");
using (var xmlWriter = xPathNavigator.AppendChild())
{
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, valueTableObject, nameSpaces);
}
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=net-6.0&force_isolation=true.  You also have to add to the [XmlElement(XmlNamespace = "the URL added in the manager")]